# Mongodb and search in nested elements

Tags: mongodb

There is a document collection like this:

```
{
   "objects": [
     {
       "a": 1,
       "prop":2,
     },
     {
       "a": 2,
       "prop":3
     } 
    ] 
}
```

There is a task to find documents with subdocument with identical properties. Let's say need find a document that contains two nested document with the property and == 1
I built a condition:

```
{
    "objects": { "$elemMatch": { "$and": [ {"a":1}, { "a":1} ]} }
}
```

or

```
{
   'objects': { $elemMatch: {'a': 1}, $size: 2 }
}
```

This query will return as expected me a document where there is any subdocument with the property 'a'= 1 and 'a' = 2, 'a'= x, etc .. And here is how to make a request that he gave me only those documents, where there are two sub-document with the properties of a = 1.
Ideally it should return only documents of this type:

```
{
   "objects": [
     {
       "a": 1,
       "prop":5
     },
     {
       "a": 1,
       "prop":6 
     } 
    ] 
}
```

Should return the documents that have two nested subarrays with the property "a" = 1

I would be very grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try do it through [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator.

With [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator to filter the value of `object.a` is `1`, then to match the size of filtered result with `2` through `$eq` and `$size`. Eventually, output the result through `$redact`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $redact: {
        $cond: [
             {$eq: [
                    {$size: {
                         $filter: {
                                   input: '$objects', 
                                   as: 'item', 
                                   cond: {$eq: ['$$item.a', 1]}
                     }}},
                     2]
             },
         '$$KEEP', 
         '$$PRUNE'
         ]}
}]);
```